# iPhone app installs through cydia in root folder instead of /Applications

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cydia

The app is developed in Xcode 4.2, SDK 5.0, tested on an iPhone 4 with 4.2.1 on. As I said in the title, the app installs itself from cydia in the root folder instead of /Applications one. Any suggestions? I double checked everything in xcode, the install is set to go to /Applications.

Comment: Please provide some more information about how you are preparing and executing your install.

Comment: Well, I fake code signed it, clicked build, took the .App file and uploaded it on myrepospace and installed with cydia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is most likely with the Debian archive that Cydia is using to install the app, check the .deb file and see what folder the app is set to extract to